# How to resolve error "Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore document" while using firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am performing a simple operation where in im trying to increment the count of a field. the code is below:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const DocumentRef = db.doc(`pages/${request.params.pageId}`);

const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);

DocumentRef
    .get()
    .then(function (documentSnapshot) {
        if(!documentSnapshot.exists){
            return response.status(404).json({"message":"page not found"})
        }else{
            return db.collection(`comments`).add(newComment)
        }
    })
    .then(()=>{
        return DocumentRef.update({nComments: increment})
    })
    .then(() => {
        response.status(200).json(newComment);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        return response.status(500).json({message:error.code});
    })
```

ending up in following error:

```
Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore document. Couldn't serialize object of type "FieldValueDelegate" (found in field "nComments"). Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the "new" operator).
    at WriteBatch.update (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:374:23)
    at DocumentReference.update (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:377:14)
    at screamDocumentRef.get.then.then (/srv/lib/handlers/screams.js:105:34)
    at <anonymous>
```

The message is:

> Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore document. Couldn't serialize object of type "FieldValueDelegate" (found in field "nComments"). Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the "new" operator).

this error happens only when I add this "then" chain:

```
.then(()=>{
        return DocumentRef.update({nComments: increment})
    })
```

I do not understand why.

only relevant part of the schema, I've 2 collections.

```
   collection: pages(nComments, body, etc)    id: pageId 
   collection: comments(pageId, etc)          id: commentId

when new comment document is added in comments collection, Im updating the count in pages collections document whose pageId is in comment documents pageId field.

nComments and pageId are fields.
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you created the `db` variable.  There should be enough information here so that anyone can copy the code and reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DougStevenson please check it out

Comment: @DougStevenson the issue comes only while adding return DocumentRef.update({nComments: increment})

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem.  Please edit the question to answer my question above.  How are you creating db?  The code you show here needs to be complete.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ive manually created two collections, (pages and comments) and entered sample data, when I add a new comment document, I want to update count of comments inside a pages document. also should I do this via batch / transactions? since Im adding a document in one collection as well as updating count in another document from another collection?

Comment: I understand from `return response.status(404).json({"message":"page not found"})` and `request.params` that this code is from an HTTP Cloud Function. If this is right, can you add the **entire content** of your `index.ts/index/js` file?

Comment: Try using this in your `DocumentRef.update` instead of a json object: `DocumentRef.update('nComments', firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1))`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hey @RafaelLemos, I tried out your way as well, doesn't seem to work.
Also, xaovnumwsercy, kindly leave an update if you have found an answer to this question or made some progress.

Answer (score 11):

You're probably using `admin` namespace to do the update while using `increment` from the `firebase` namespace. Try changing your increment statement to:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const increment = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
```